# RNG Character Printing Function - More than one line of RNG characters per page? : C

Tags: c, random, character, console-application, windows-console

So, I wrote a function (and an RNG function, which the aforementioned function calls) to print a random number of asterisks to the console window, until it hits 90 spaces. The asterisks represent the movement of a car, and the 90 spaces is the length of the track. The code I've included below prints a random number of asterisks until it hits 90 spaces, assuming the fnvMoveSpaces() function is called in main and the user presses a key to resume the loop after each system("PAUSE") until 90 spaces is hit.

My question is, looking at the provided code, how would I get four *separate lines of totally independent **RNG** character printing **on the same page of the console window?*** It needs to look like a legitimate race, on the same screen.

What I've tried:

1) Separate functions for each line, called in main:

- Won't work, as they don't happen at the same time. Results in four different pages. I.e. the user has to press a key to get through system("PAUSE") until it hits 90 spaces, then the next function does the same, then the next, and the next. Also, if the loop/function call is outside of the fnvMoveSpaces() main loop, they don't print to the same page.

2) Putting four of the same for loops in the fnvMoveSpaces() function:

- This prints four lines to the same screen, but they all move the same increment, because they are pulling from the same RNG value.

Basically, the RNG values for each line need to be totally independent of one another. Would having a different seed value for each line be the answer? I have no idea...

```
   /* - - DEFINED - - */
// Constants of RNG for spaces moved
#define TRACK_LENGTH 90
#define MAX_MOVE_SPACES 10
#define MIN_MOVE_SPACES 1


// Assume fnvMoveSpaces call in main


// Function to create random number for car movement
int fniRandGenMove()
{
    // Declare
    int randInt;

    // Initialize random seed
    srand(time(NULL));

    // Formula for RNG (1-10) based on global-defined numbers
    randInt = (rand() % (MAX_MOVE_SPACES - MIN_MOVE_SPACES + 1) + MIN_MOVE_SPACES);

    return (randInt);

}


void fnvMoveSpaces()
{
    // Declare
    int i;
    int iMoveSum;

    // Outer for loop to maintain the sum of asterisks
    for(iMoveSum = 0; iMoveSum <= TRACK_LENGTH; iMoveSum += fniRandGenMove())
    {
        // Inner for loop to print asterisks
        for(i = 0; i < iMoveSum; i++)
        {
            putchar('*');

        }

        // Newline for next line of asterisks
        printf("\n");

        /*
        I'm assuming three more for loops... I tried a bunch of
        combinations of things, even making new iMoveSums
        (2, 3 and 4) and doing for loops.
        But, no luck.

        I should also not that making four separate functions for each
        line of asterisks will not work, unless there is a way to call all
        four at once in main. Separate functions results in separate screens
        in the console window. In addition, if the four 'putchar' blocks
        are not in the same loop as a whole, the first one will print, hit
        90 spaces, then the second, etc... They aren't on the same screen.
        */

        // System pause to wait for user
        system("PAUSE");
        // Clear screen
        system("CLS");

    }

}
```

Just to clarify, the current output of this in the console window is this:

**.....*

(Writing in a form of enumeration; no periods actually output.)

Until 90 spaces are hit, then the program closes. Also keep in mind that it prints in random *increments* each time the user presses a key after system("PAUSE"), until 90. So, not all the asterisks print at once.

What I want it to output is something like this:

*...**

*.........**

**........................*

**..............*

With each line randomly generating its own independent *movement increment*, until 90 spaces are hit.

Hope that helps.

Thanks,

Bagger

Comment: Please have a look at [SetConsoleCursorPosition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686025(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Please just seed the RNG once. Then call the RNG itself once for every car movement.

Comment: @ Weather Vane Let me try that second comment.

Comment: @ Weather Vane I got it, and thanks a lot for telling me to seed the RNG just once. That was one of the biggest issues. Everything else was just formatting the loops. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got it worked out. Keep in mind that at some point in the near future, I intend to replace the structures with some file I/O. Also, fniRandGenMove is the same as in the question, just move the seed to main, so it only seeds once.

But it works perfectly... the 'cars' race across the console window! It's actually really neat.

```
    void fnvMoveSpaces(int iAutoManual)
{
    // Declare
    int i, j;

    // Declare structures
    struct Car stCars[4];
    stCars[0].iPosition = 0;
    stCars[1].iPosition = 0;
    stCars[2].iPosition = 0;
    stCars[3].iPosition = 0;
    stCars[0].iCarNumber = 1;
    stCars[1].iCarNumber = 2;
    stCars[2].iCarNumber = 3;
    stCars[3].iCarNumber = 4;


    struct Car furthestCar;
    furthestCar.iPosition = 0;
    furthestCar.iCarNumber = 0;

    do
    {
        for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            if(stCars[i].iPosition <= TRACK_LENGTH)
            {
                stCars[i].iPosition += fniRandGenMove();

            }

            printf("Car %d\n\t", stCars[i].iCarNumber);

            for(j = 0; j < stCars[i].iPosition; j++)
            {
                printf("*");

            }

            if (stCars[i].iPosition > furthestCar.iPosition)
            {
                furthestCar.iPosition = stCars[i].iPosition;
                furthestCar.iCarNumber = stCars[i].iCarNumber;

            }

            printf("\n");

        }

        system("PAUSE");
        system("CLS");

    } while(furthestCar.iPosition < TRACK_LENGTH);


    printf("The winning car is #%d.\n", furthestCar.iCarNumber);

}
```